# WSDL TO PHP implementation

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I got converted WSDL to PHP script but something is not working very I am trying to connect http://www.regcheck.org.uk/api/reg.asmx?wsdl, but getting this error

```html
Array ( [RegCheckServiceCheck::Check] => SoapFault Object ( [message:protected] => System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at webtropy.CarReg.Check(String RegistrationNumber, String username) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\regcheck.org.uk\api\reg.asmx:line 26 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 0 [file:protected] => C:\xampp\htdocs\Check\RegCheckServiceCheck.php [line:protected] => 32 [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\Check\RegCheckServiceCheck.php [line] => 32 [function] => __call [class] => SoapClient [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => Check [1] => Array ( [0] => RegCheckStructCheck Object ( [RegistrationNumber] => [username] => [result:RegCheckWsdlClass:private] => [lastError:RegCheckWsdlClass:private] => Array ( ) [internArrayToIterate:RegCheckWsdlClass:private] => [internArrayToIterateIsArray:RegCheckWsdlClass:private] => [internArrayToIterateOffset:RegCheckWsdlClass:private] => ) ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\Check\RegCheckServiceCheck.php [line] => 32 [function] => Check [class] => SoapClient [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => RegCheckStructCheck Object ( [RegistrationNumber] => [username] => [result:RegCheckWsdlClass:private] => [lastError:RegCheckWsdlClass:private] => Array ( ) [internArrayToIterate:RegCheckWsdlClass:private] => [internArrayToIterateIsArray:RegCheckWsdlClass:private] => [internArrayToIterateOffset:RegCheckWsdlClass:private] => ) ) ) [2] => Array ( [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\sample-regcheck.php [line] => 46 [function] => Check [class] => RegCheckServiceCheck [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => RegCheckStructCheck Object ( [RegistrationNumber] => [username] => [result:RegCheckWsdlClass:private] => [lastError:RegCheckWsdlClass:private] => Array ( ) [internArrayToIterate:RegCheckWsdlClass:private] => [internArrayToIterateIsArray:RegCheckWsdlClass:private] => [internArrayToIterateOffset:RegCheckWsdlClass:private] => ) ) ) ) [previous:Exception:private] => [faultstring] => System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at webtropy.CarReg.Check(String RegistrationNumber, String username) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\regcheck.org.uk\api\reg.asmx:line 26 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- [faultcode] => soap:Server [detail] => ) )
```

I am sure something is missing in config files, mybe someone got idea ?

Comment: Please post your complete code.

Comment: Please edit your question and remove the snippet

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to call that web service via a HTTP GET request as follows;

```
<?php
$username = 'Your username here';
$regNumber = 'SK08KPT';
$xmlData = file_get_contents("https://www.regcheck.org.uk/api/reg.asmx/Check?RegistrationNumber=" . $regNumber  ."&username=" . $username);
$xml=simplexml_load_string($xmlData);    
$strJson = $xml->vehicleJson;    
$json = json_decode($strJson);    
print_r($json->Description);    
?>
```

Not as elegant as a SOAP call, but simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Script open source files

You can see all main files
https://www.wsdltophp.com/Wsdls/8a71627601a684624c5694104cce023f/RegCheck-1-0-1-1-1-1-0-0-0-0

Comment: Please add more context and explain in which sense this answers your question.